# string comparison in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>inline-block </td>
    <td>blank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>none </td>
    <td>blank</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${a}==${blank}</td>
    <td>labelA</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['a']==storedVars['blank']</td>
    <td>ddddd</td>
</tr>
```

I want to compare strings variables, i tried both the scenarios i mentioned above. This both scenarios are not working for string comparison

Comment: what you have stored in a?? You have defined both value for blank variable

Comment: oops my mistake one of them is a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Selenium.prototype.doVerifyStringsEquals = function(elementOne, elementTwo) 
{
    var arrayelements = elementOne.split(',');
    var one = arrayelements[0];
    var two = arrayelements[1];
    if(one == two) 
    {
        storedVars[ elementTwo ] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        storedVars[ elementTwo ] = 0;
    }
};



<tr>
    <td>verifyEquals</td>
    <td>test,test</td>
    <td>t</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${t}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code into your javascript file

```
Selenium.prototype.assertEquals = function(elementOne, elementTwo) 
{
    if(elementOne != elementTwo) 
    {
        Assert.fail("" + elementOne + " is not equal to " + elementTwo);
    }
};
```

and

|assertEquals | 10 | 10 |

This hope will help compare the two strings.